# Users at same level in Role Hierarchy to Delete Products created by others

Tags: permissions, product2

If two users are at the same level in the Role Hierarchy is it possible to allow them to delete each-others `Product2` records without the `Modify All data` permission?

I see [as of Summer '22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_features_core_products_sharing_defaults.htm&type=5&release=236) it will be possible to have sharing rules (IE granting Read/Write access) on `Product2`, however, there is no "Modify All" setting on `Product2`.

Comment: You could do it indirectly by having the OOTB Delete button replaced by a Screen Flow that published a Platform Event that did the delete. Screen flow could detect the role hierarchy equivalence

Comment: @cropredy smh - seems hackish but if that's what it takes :P I appreciate it!